# old gen filling up in one node

Tags: performance

We observed very high Full GC in one of the node during load test. We used 3 glassfish nodes. IN other 2 nodes GC usage is normal, but in node 1 objects not being able to released and slowly objects reach `XMX settings`. I've verified all 3 nodes `JVM settings`. They are same. Verified server logs and the load in 3 nodes are same. Not sure why 1 node have this GC issue and not other nodes.

JVM settings:

```
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:ParallelGCThreads=8 -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:NewRatio=2 -XX:+LogVMOutput -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:LogFile=/opt/glassfish/domains/xyz/logs/jvm.log -Xmx4096m -Xms4096m
```

O/S: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.6 (Tikanga)

```
JVM Version  
java version "1.6.0_24"  
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b07)  
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
```

Here is sample of GC from problematic node during FULL GC.

```
 323233.103: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1305536K->1041065K(1351872K)] [PSOldGen: 2796223K->2796223K(2796224K)] 4101759K->3837289K(4148096K) [PSPermGen: 105778K->105778K(106048K)], 24.3236370 secs] [Times: user=24.32 sys=0.00, real=24.32 secs] 
323264.008: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1305536K->1106487K(1351872K)] [PSOldGen: 2796223K->2796223K(2796224K)] 4101759K->3902711K(4148096K) [PSPermGen: 105778K->105778K(106048K)], 22.2367020 secs] [Times: user=22.22 sys=0.01, real=22.24 secs] 
323291.647: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1305536K->1106550K(1351872K)] [PSOldGen: 2796223K->2796223K(2796224K)] 4101759K->3902774K(4148096K) [PSPermGen: 105778K->105778K(106048K)], 22.0651020 secs] [Times: user=22.06 sys=0.00, real=22.06 secs] 
323318.604: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1305536K->1106756K(1351872K)] [PSOldGen: 2796223K->2796223K(2796224K)] 4101759K->3902980K(4148096K) [PSPermGen: 105778K->105778K(106048K)], 22.4309650 secs] [Times: user=22.42 sys=0.00, real=22.43 secs] 
323345.717: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1305536K->1041019K(1351872K)] [PSOldGen: 2796223K->2796223K(2796224K)] 4101759K->3837243K(4148096K) [PSPermGen: 105778K->105778K(106048K)], 24.6671980 secs] [Times: user=24.65 sys=0.00, real=24.66 secs] 
323377.049: [Full GC [PSYoungGen: 1305536K->1102486K(1351872K)] [PSOldGen: 2796223K->2796223K(2796224K)] 4101759K->3898710K(4148096K) [PSPermGen: 105778K->105778K(106048K)], 22.5150360 secs] [Times: user=22.50 sys=0.00, real=22.51 secs]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to troubleshoot would be to find out what the objects in the old generation are. This can be done by using `jmap -histo` option.

run `jps` notedown the process id and then invoke `jmap -histo pid`. You will get a count of objects for each class.

It could be caching/session replication or some back ground task that runs on one node that is causing the problem.  Finding out the class(es) that is filling up memory will point you to the problem.

Comment: Thanks gkamal. I will execute jmap and let you know. Will this dump a log file and if yes where is the location. Which tool you use to analyze jmap logs. However my question is why in node 1 i've GC issue while other 2 nodes i do not have. If somebody came across this kind of issue, please share your exxperience.